# Google Ajax Search API no results from site:mywebsite.com

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, google-api

I'm using Google Search API for my website.
Everything works fine from all search queries except one ! 
Queries contain `site:noviniran.com` returns no results !!!!
I don't know why ! this query works on normal Google.com but it returns nothing on Google Search API.

Check out:

> http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=site:noviniran.com

Other Queries return results with no problam:

> http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=site:iran.com
>
> http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=site:iranair.com
>
> http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=site:irannovin.com

What's Going On With My 1 Year Old Website ? :(

Sorry for bad English,

Thank you in advance

Comment: no one can help me on this ???

Comment: That API is deprecated, so my guess is that it's not using the same search index as the public Google search. The new search API is at https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/overview

Comment: I know it's deprecated but why it works from other queries ?

Comment: Maybe because those are older sites? I tried with a site I own and the returned results are from 2009

Answer (score 0):

As I tested this now it responded with `The Google Web Search API is no longer available. Please migrate to the Google Custom Search API`. So I'm gonna try my best to give an example how the `custom search api` works.

```js
function getData(query, engine, search_key) {
 /*
  Info about google custom search API:
 
  The first 100 queries per day are free. 
  Any more, then you have to pay $5 per 1000 queries, for up to 10,000 queries per day, 
  just enable billing to do so. Each query returns a maximum of 10 results, 
  so you can retrieve 1000 URL’s from your search per day for free.
 */
 
 var API_KEY = search_key;
 var ENGINE_ID = engine;
 var API_URL = `https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=${API_KEY}&cx=${ENGINE_ID}&searchType=image&q=${query}`;
  
  jQuery.getJSON(API_URL, {
            tags: query,
            tagmode: "any",
            format: "json"
        },
        function(data) {
            //do something
        });
}
```

```html
<div id="image" onload="getData("your_search", "your_engine_id", "your_key")"></div>
```

But before running this snippet, first create an `API key` on Google for this and a `custom search engine` which you will need it's `ID`. Also after you created a `custom engine` you need to enable the `Image search` option.

[API console](https://console.developers.google.com/cloud-resource-manager)

[Search engine](https://cse.google.com/all)

[Custom search API key](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview)

When you created this you need to make sure you have a string build in which requests the `api key` and `search engine ID` like this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=${API_KEY}&cx=${ENGINE_ID}&searchType=image&q=${query}
```

Second part is that you need to set the string into the `getJSON` as you want the data from that search like this:

```
jQuery.getJSON(API_URL, {
            tags: query,
            tagmode: "any",
            format: "json"
        },
```

Last you want a function to close off the `json`, so you can do whatever you want with the data like this:

```
function(data) {
    //do whatever
});
```

Remember this is just an example to help you further ahead in the project.